# Does Python hashlib's sha256 employ the Intel SHA extensions?

Tags: x86, sha256, cpython, instruction-set, hardware-acceleration

Does CPython hashlib's SHA256 employ the [Intel SHA extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions)
? If yes, since which version(s)?

Since CPython uses OpenSSL for its crypto primitives it should also use its hardware acceleration capabilities (AESNI-SHA256 was added to OpenSSL [between 1.0.1l and 1.0.2](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=CHANGES.md;h=7c934935eb1a8112a63baab25694cef41cdf923e;hb=HEAD#l5437) on 22 Jan 2015), but I can't find out if and since when SHA256 hardware acceleration is used.  I tried to understand [the sha256module.c source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/sha256module.c) but got lost in the abstractions :(

Bonus question: AFAIK, the CPython for Windows release statically links OpenSSL. When was it upgraded to a version of OpenSSL that can theoretically use SHA-NI, and: Does it use them? (Sorry, I couldn't even Google *that*)

Comment: For Python 3.8, I have tested both WSL and Windows and both "seem" to use the extensions. I basically wrote a C program that I know for a fact uses the extensions and compared the speeds. There is only ~1 second of difference over 100m hashes.

Answer (score 2):

CPython has used OpenSSL's hash primitives when available for many years.

OpenSSL added hardware-accelerated SHA256 in 1.0.2 [22 Jan 2015]. From the changelog:

```
  * Support for new and upcoming Intel processors, including AVX2,
    BMI and SHA ISA extensions. This includes additional "stitched"
    implementations, AESNI-SHA256 and GCM, and multi-buffer support
    for TLS encrypt.
 
    This work was sponsored by Intel Corp.
```

This means that CPython has supported hardware-assisted SHA256 hashing on at least some platforms since 3.5.

In Python 3.12 CPython switched to using HACL (see [the commit, with benchmark results](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1fcc0efdaa84b3602c236391633b70ff36df149b)) which improves hashing performance considerably.